# MySql: Delete from table with join

Tags: mysql

I need to delete records from a child table (`table_b`) based on the status of matching records in the parent table (`table_a`).  Something like this:

```
delete from table_b b inner join table_a a on b.user_id = a.id where a.status = 0;
```

But MySql says there is an error in the syntax.

I also tried the following:

```
delete from table_b where user_id in (
  select id from table_a a inner join table_b b on a.id = b.user_id 
  where a.status = 0)
```

But evidently I cannot specify a table for update and simultaneously include it in the `FROM` clause.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: try this   delete b.* from table_b b  ...

Comment: can you post your table columns?